# How do I create simple two page Android swipe app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a tabbed activity or empty activity in Android Studio, but I need to be able to swipe to a page 2.

All I would like is for the app to say the standard *"Hello World"* on the 1st screen, and then you can swipe to the next page that says *"Hello World Page 2"*, Just those 2 screens with no title bar on any of the screens - that's it.

I've tried creating a tabbed activity and was able to create both pages and swipe works, but it creates a button in the lower right corner and a title bar with settings button up top that I couldn't figure out how to delete.

I tried an empty activity but couldn't figure out how to add another page. If anyone could provide me the code or a sample project I could edit that would be amazing as I've lost several days in frustration over this.

Comment: Why is it so hard ? just create a new project with tabbed activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ViewPager` component. When you will use it you would to use `TabLayout`, but if you want to hide it you just simply can edit its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this Example.

- https://www.sitepoint.com/using-viewpager-to-create-a-sliding-screen-ui-in-android/
- Simply replace the image with TextView.
- To hide the actionbar user  getSupportActionBar().hide()